# How to run java code from shell script on linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, classpath, sh

I want to set a cron job for my java code and I have tried this from project directory

```
    java -classpath .:/home/project/lib/* pkg_name.my_code
```

and it works fine, however I dont know how to run it from any other directory[like in script]
I have tried to add diroctry (having compiled classes) in classpath like this

```
    java -classpath .:/home/project/lib/*;/home/project/pkg_name/* pkg_name.my_code
```

also tried

```
    java -classpath ".:/home/project/lib/*;/home/project/pkg_name/*" pkg_name.my_code
```

but it gives error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class pkg_name.my_code
**

can any please help me ?

Comment: you have a jar file? a class file? or a `.java` file?

Comment: Try removing the wildcards. Just put the name of the directory containing the packages, or the full name (directory+filename) of the jars. e.g.: `-classpath /home/project:/home/project/lib/someJar.jar:/home/project/lib/someOtherJar.jar`

Comment: in lib I have jars, and under pakg_name class (compiled one) file, which I want to run

Comment: @Benjamin tried but not working

Comment: Assuming that your class name is `my_code` in the package `pkg_name`, the following should work: `java -classpath /home/project:/home/project/lib/someJar.jar:/home/project/lib/someOtherJar.jar pkg_name.my_code`

Comment: this? `java -classpath ".:/home/project/lib/*;/home/project" pkg_name.mycode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your project from another directory, then you need to include your project in classpath. So you can do this

```
java -classpath ".:/home/project/lib/*:/home/project" pkg_name.my_code
```

For example :

```
java -classpath ".:/home/test/runjavafromanotherdirectory/lib/*:./runjavafromanotherdirectory" com.test.Main
```

One of your mistake is you are using `;` instead of `:`.